# Select line matching pattern +1

Tags: sed

How do I use *sed* to select every line matching a pattern + the next line?
For instance, I'd like to select all lines with *tag="foo"* plus the next line.
As an alternative, I'd also like to be able to select lines with *tag="foo"* OR *group="bar"* plus the next line.

Comment: You should consider using awk instead of sed, as it's just more obvious what's going in with awk.

Comment: When that is said, I think something like this might work for you: `sed -n '/pattern/ { N; p }'`.

Comment: Or, `sed -n '/foo/{N;p;D}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/tag="foo"|group="bar"/,+1p' file
```

Turn on extended regexp `-E` and off implicit printing `-n`.

Match the alternation of `tag="foo"` or `group="bar"` and print the range `+1` line(s).

---

Alternative:

```
sed '/tag="foo"\|group="bar"/!d;n' file
```

---

To always print 2 lines, use:

```
sed -n '/tag="foo"\|group="bar"/{N;p}' file
```